# No puedo correr el programa de OR-Tools para python porque me falta un modulo. Como lo descargo?

Tags: python, optimización

Descargue mediante la ventana de comando de anaconda OR-tools pero al parece no me incluye el modulo de _pywraplp.

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywraplp: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.

Answer (score 0):

OR-Tools necesita c++ dado que lo que intentas instalar en un wrapper alrededor de código c++. Te recomiendo instalar previamente Visual Studio de este sitio: visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/downloads

Comment: desconocía que estaba enmascarado, el link es del mismo sitio que tu mencionas